# Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider with MySql + MVC4

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

We are getting the following error when we tried running our MVC4 Project with Azure Mysql DB.

In Web.Config file we have the following,

```
<DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

**Error:**

> Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException:
>   Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider.

Source Error:

```
Line 96:             if (objectQuery != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
Line 97:             {
Line 98:                 return objectQuery.Include(path);
Line 99:             }
Line 100:

Source File: C:\Phase2\FreeLance\FreeLance\Framework\Data\FreeLance.Data.Framework\EntityFramework\Extensions.cs    Line: 98 

Stack Trace: 


[ConfigurationErrorsException: Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider.]
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(DataRow providerRow) +2238858
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory(String providerString) +143
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString) +641
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config) +144
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize() +95
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel() +16
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +269
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +26
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +71
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Include(String path) +25
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.Include(String path) +111
   FreeLance.Data.Framework.EntityFramework.Extensions.Include(IQueryable`1 source, String path) in C:\Phase2\FreeLance\FreeLance\Framework\Data\FreeLance.Data.Framework\EntityFramework\Extensions.cs:98
   FreeLance.Data.Framework.EntityFramework.Extensions.Include(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 expression) in C:\Phase2\FreeLance\FreeLance\Framework\Data\FreeLance.Data.Framework\EntityFramework\Extensions.cs:64
   FreeLance.Data.Framework.EntityFramework.Extensions.Include(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1[] expressions) in C:\Phase2\FreeLance\FreeLance\Framework\Data\FreeLance.Data.Framework\EntityFramework\Extensions.cs:79
   FreeLance.Data.Framework.EntityFramework.Repository`1.GetAll(Expression`1[] include) in C:\Phase2\FreeLance\FreeLance\Framework\Data\FreeLance.Data.Framework\EntityFramework\Repository.cs:89
   FreeLance.Business.PageBC.GetPages() in C:\Phase2\FreeLance\FreeLance\Business\FreeLance.Business\Admin\PageBC.cs:49
   FreeLance.Services.PageService.GetPages() in C:\Phase2\FreeLance\FreeLance\Services\FreeLance.Services\PageService.cs:54
   FreeLance.Web.Helpers.DataHelper.GetAppPages() in C:\Phase2\FreeLance\FreeLance\User Interface\FreeLance.Web\Helpers\DataHelper.cs:250
   FreeLance.Web.ResourceConfig.GetAppPages() in C:\Phase2\FreeLance\FreeLance\User Interface\FreeLance.Web\App_Start\ResourceConfig.cs:64
   FreeLance.Web.AppConfig.Run() in C:\Phase2\FreeLance\FreeLance\User Interface\FreeLance.Web\App_Start\AppConfig.cs:55
   FreeLance.Web.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in C:\Phase2\FreeLance\FreeLance\User Interface\FreeLance.Web\Global.asax.cs:40

[HttpException (0x80004005): Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +4054645
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +191
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +352
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +407
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +375

[HttpException (0x80004005): Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +11646640
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +141
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +4869909
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Make sure you have added **MySql.Data.Entity.dll** & **MySql.Data.dll** files in the bin of the MVC project

Answer (score 4):

If using Mono make sure you also have MySQL Data Provider node in machine.config. I'm using 4.5 so *for me* it's */opt/mono/4.5/machine.config*(example location):

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" /> 
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

You can find machine.config location by running simple command in Linux:

```
cd / && find -name 'machine.config'
```

You may need `sudo` before `find` command on Ubuntu:

```
cd / && sudo find -name 'machine.config'
```